# Determine if any array value compared against a given string has a qualifying levenshtein score

Tags: php, arrays, levenshtein-distance

I want to verify if a levenshtein of factor `<= 2` is present in an array. So:

```
in_array("test", $some_array);
```

to something like "check if in array, can have errors if levenshtein factor `<= 2`, by comparison"

```
levenshtein("test", $element_of_array_by_'in_array'_function);
```

Is this possible or do I have to iterate the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

You are looking for [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php). With this you can reduce your array to one single return value.

You start with `FALSE` as return value. Then you loop through each array element and check if the return value of `levenshtein()` is smaller or equals 2.

If not then your return value of `array_reduce()` won't change and is still `FALSE`. If it is smaller or equals 2 you change the value to `TRUE` and `array_reduce()` will return `TRUE`.

```
array_reduce($some_array, function($keep, $v){
    if(levenshtein($v, "test") <= 2)
        return $keep = TRUE;
    return $keep;
}, FALSE);
```

Comment: just one question, how can I separate the function to run and send "test" (it's a variable, so it changes) to the function as well? I have

    `function levenshteinArray($keep,$v){
        if(levenshtein($v, $have_this_variable(not_from_array_but_also_varies) ) <= 2) return $keep = TRUE;
    return $keep;
    }

   array_reduce($array,"levenshteinArray",FALSE);`

Comment: @Fane Since it is an anonymous function you can use `use()`, e.g. `... function($keep, $v)use($have_this_variable){ ...` and then you can use the variable in the function

Answer (score 0):

The following is an optimized version of Rizier123's answer.  The performance improvement is that once `$result` is returned as `true`, `levenshtein()` will not be called for the remaining values and `true` will be the final result.

Also, using arrow function syntax, means that the `$needle` is available to the callback function without needing `use()`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/3SZI7))

```
$haystack = ['drat', 'that', 'darn', 'brat', ];
$needle = 'fart';
var_export(
    array_reduce(
        $haystack,
        fn($result, $hay) => $result ?: (levenshtein($hay, $needle) <= 2),
        false
    )
);
```

---

The only way to further improve performance would be to use a breakable loop to halt iteration as soon a `true` evaluation is encountered. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/IQTNX))

```
$haystack = ['drat', 'that', 'darn', 'brat', ];
$needle = 'fart';
$result = false;
foreach ($haystack as $hay) {
    if (levenshtein($hay, $needle) <= 2) {
        $result = true;
        break;
    }
}
var_export($result);
```